# Android WiFiManager - Occasionally throwing error when setWiFiEnabled is used

Tags: android

Has anyone experienced a problem where the

```
I/WifiManager(22480): setWifiEnabled : true
E/WifiManager(22480): java.lang.Throwable
E/WifiManager(22480):  at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.setWifiEnabled(WifiManager.java:959)
```

I seem to be having this happening hit/miss when turning on or off the Wi-Fi radio through the android APIs.  It is being used in the function below:

```
public static void manageWiFiRadio(Context context, String onoff)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "managerWiFiRadio(context, " + onoff + " )");
    try 
    {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        Thread.sleep(250);
        if ( onoff == "on")
        {
            if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
            {
                Thread.sleep(250);
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            }
            else Log.d(TAG,"WiFi is already" + onoff);
        }
        else if( onoff == "off")
        {
            if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled())
            {
                Thread.sleep(250);
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }
            else Log.d(TAG,"WiFi is already" + onoff);
        }   

    }
    catch (Exception e) {Log.d(TAG, "There was an exception in wifi e:" + e);}
    wifiManager = null;
}
```

I added the sleeps above for debugging but that only lowered the reproduction rate.

For testing, I've executed this on a Sprint Samsung Galaxy S III and a Sprint HTC Evo 4G and both are having this problem.  When the error is thrown, it is caught within the Android OS but the Wi-Fi radio never changes state.

Comment: I'm seen the same error, on Samsung Note 3 device, when i try to enable tethering via code or via system configs. Have you found more answers?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Thread.sleep(250);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
```

to

```
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
Thread.sleep(250);
```

Comment: I tried all the common changes, timings etc etc like that.  It made no difference.